# Heroku push does not upload migrations

Tags: django, heroku

I have developed a Django project and want to deploy it on a Heroku server. The problem is that my migrations are not uploaded after 'heroku push' command.

After I run

```
python ./Code/manage.py makemigrations
python ./Code/manage.py migrate
```

I see my migration files and database locally. But, after that, when I push them to Heroku, they seem not to be there. My website on Heroku gives the error that some tables are not available and when I run bash on the server to see my files there aren't any migration files and the migration folders in my apps only have the **init**.py file. 
I even tried to make the migrations and migrate on the release phase. This is the Procfile:

```
release: bash ./release_tasks.sh
web: gunicorn --pythonpath Code Code.wsgi --log-file -
```

and this is release_tasks.sh:

```
python ./Code/manage.py makemigrations
python ./Code/manage.py migrate
```

Again, when I push to Heroku everything is ok and I see the correct migration messages, which shows that migration was successfully carried out. But still, there is no migration file on the server and my website gives the same error.

Here is what I don't understand:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8cxP.jpg)
I have migrations locally and Git is up-to-date, but I don't have them on the server.

Comment: Did you include your migrations in the subversioning system?

Comment: yes. I use git and add and commit my changes.

Answer (score 0):

As with any code you create locally, you need to add it to git and then commit.

```
./Code/manage.py makemigrations
git add ....
git commit
git push origin heroku
```

You should remove the makemigrations step from the release tasks, there is no point running that on Heroku.

Comment: I add and commit my changes. Still, they are not on Heroku server after push. The reason for makemigrations command on release phase was that I do not have migrations on the server and single migrate command gives error: